# How to get a VBA script to work for variable field?

Tags: vba, sap-gui, sap-erp

I have a requirement to change the date on work orders during Technical completion and have written a script.  The issue is with some work orders the field name is `RIARCH-ADDAT` and some other work orders use `RIWO1-BEZDT` for the close date.

How do I edit my script to work for either field name?

```
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRIARCH-ADDAT").Text = B
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRIWO1-BEZDT").Text = B
```

Currently I run the script for one field, then change it and run it again.  I just can't get it to work :(

Thanks all!

Comment: Please add some more of your script for context. Ideally we could see the part that changes the dates, not just the lines that find them. It will help if you provide enough for others to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```
...
on error resume next
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRIARCH-ADDAT").Text = B 
if err.number <> 0 then Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRIWO1-BEZDT").Text = B
on error goto 0
...
```

Regards, ScriptMan